# Javamail Transport.send(message) dosn't work in android using kotlin

Tags: android, email, kotlin, jakarta-mail, transport

I want to send an email to a user, i have followed many tutorials, and i did what they did, but, when i want to execute Transport.send(message) the program stops on this line,

```
    suspend fun sendEmail()   {
  
    try {
        val props = Properties()
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        Log.d(TAG, "sendEmail: one")
        val session = Session.getInstance(props, object : Authenticator() {
            override fun getPasswordAuthentication(): PasswordAuthentication {
                return PasswordAuthentication("my email ", "my password")
            }
        })
        val mm = MimeMessage(session)
        mm.setFrom(InternetAddress("my email"))
        mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress("recipient email"))
        mm.subject = "subject"
        mm.setText("hi how are you")
        Log.d(TAG, "sendEmail: two")
        Transport.send(mm)
        Log.d(TAG, "sendEmail: three")
        
        


    }catch (e: MessagingException){
        Log.d(TAG, "sendEmail: ${e.message}")
       throw Exception(e.message)
        
    }

}
```

i can log one and two but three won't show, also i can't log what is inside the exception catch

any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution, i should have launched sendEmail() with a coroutine confined into Dispatchers.IO